# INSTALL_FAILED_ACWF_INCOMPATIBLE installation error

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, deployment

I'm very new to android development on eclipse, I have an **ZTE v856** with **Android 2.3.3**, I'm trying to debug the app on my device but I get the following error when the app is trying to install:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_ACWF_INCOMPATIBLE
```

I tried to search in Internet for the error but no luck, anyone knows what's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall some large apps, to free your mobile's internal memory.

I've been searching google for a week to try to solve this problem, and I randomly decided to uninstall some of the applications. I had 10MB free, my app had 600KB, but after unistalling some apps, it worked.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling few apps that free some memory, normally helps .